# how to tell ubuntu to use python 3.4 instead of 2.7?

Tags: 12.04, python, playonlinux

I have python 2.7 and 3.4 versions installed.
But when I say say "python -V", it shows version as 2.7 not 3.4

How to tell ubuntu to use newest python? where is this setting configured ?

Comment: You don't. The `python` command will always be Python 2.x. If you want Python 3.x, you should use the `python3` command to run it. Changing the `python` command will break all Python 2.x applications.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch At first sight definitely, but OP doesn't want a permanent change, but just wants to know how to define which version to use, running the code (see comment on the answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you run `python -V`, you get: `Python 2.7.6`, However, if you run `python3 -V`, you get `3.4.0`.

Running a script, you can specify the python version to use by using either:

```
python <script.py>
```

or:

```
python3 <script.py>
```

If the script or application is executable, and you run it without the `python` (either 2 or 3) command, you *need* to have the shebang in your script, in which you define the python version to use; either:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

or:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

You cannot run code, written for python2 with python3 and vice versa, so you should not (try to) "tell" Ubuntu to use either version 2 or 3 in another way then above, according to the version of python, used in your code.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob, I wanted to run script with python version 3 and command python3 helped