# Cannot tell ubuntu use python3.4 instead of 2.7

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I tried this [how to tell ubuntu to use python 3.4 instead of 2.7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528009/how-to-tell-ubuntu-to-use-python-3-4-instead-of-2-7) but nothing..
I have a problem with the nonlocal

This is my code:

```
x = 50   
def func_outer():  
     x=2  
     print('x is '), x

     def func_inner():
        nonlocal x
        x=5
    func_inner()
    print('the local x changed to '),x

=>

    nonlocal x
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Do you know how to change it to python 2.7 or any alternative about nonlocal?

Comment: Your code is a bit mixed up, but simply use the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python3` If you want to use python3

Comment: I tried the shebang but nothing ..i also tried too use the shebang like this  #!/usr/bin/python3 but it gives me the syntaxError again.

Comment: @George how do you run the code?

Answer (score 1):

Such file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
x = 50   
def func_outer():  
     x=2  
     print('x is '), x

     def func_inner():
        nonlocal x
        x=5
     func_inner()
     print('the local x changed to '),x
```

when run as `./file.py` yields no errors with `python3.5` on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Well i found a solution finally!( How stupid problem) :(
At first , i was created the file (test.py) with nano. My first command was  #!/bin/usr/python then i saved my file. Every time i wanted to change the code i opened the test.py with the editor and i wrote the code there, then i just opened the terminal writing "python test.py" to run my script. This is why i couldn't run my code in python 3. I made a new file and instead of #!/bin/usr/python and i wrote #!/bin/usr/python3. The script now running in python 3.